# How to store array of objects in db.json from json-server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json-server

I am creating a fake backend using json-server to store some data in json format. The data is complex as follows -

```
   {
        "id": 0,
        "quizName": "Which Harry Potter Character Are You?",
        "characters": ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermoine"],
        "qa": [{
                "question": "Do you play Chess?",
                "answers": [{
                        "name": "yes",
                        "charscore": [0, 1, 0]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "no",
                        "charscore": [1, 0, 1]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "question": "Do you spell magic correctly?",
                "answers": [{
                        "name": "yes",
                        "charscore": [0, 0, 1]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "no",
                        "charscore": [1, 1, 0]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "question": "Do you have a Scar?",
                "answers": [{
                        "name": "yes",
                        "charscore": [1, 0, 0]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "no",
                        "charscore": [0, 1, 1]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

But when I do jQuery POST to the json-server, the json data is stored as follows -

```
{
  "quizName": "Which Harry Potter Character Are You?",
  "characters[]": [
    "Harry",
    "Ron",
    "Hermoine"
  ],
  "qa[0][question]": "Do you play Chess?",
  "qa[0][answers][0][name]": "yes",
  "qa[0][answers][0][charscore][]": [
    "0",
    "1",
    "0"
  ],
  "qa[0][answers][1][name]": "no",
  "qa[0][answers][1][charscore][]": [
    "1",
    "0",
    "1"
  ],
  "qa[1][question]": "Do you spell magic correctly?",
  "qa[1][answers][0][name]": "yes",
  "qa[1][answers][0][charscore][]": [
    "0",
    "0",
    "1"
  ],
  "qa[1][answers][1][name]": "no",
  "qa[1][answers][1][charscore][]": [
    "1",
    "1",
    "0"
  ],
  "qa[2][question]": "Do you have a Scar?",
  "qa[2][answers][0][name]": "yes",
  "qa[2][answers][0][charscore][]": [
    "1",
    "0",
    "0"
  ],
  "qa[2][answers][1][name]": "no",
  "qa[2][answers][1][charscore][]": [
    "0",
    "1",
    "1"
  ],
  "id": 1
}
```

The post method is as follows-

```
$.post(this.serverUrl, val, function (serverResponse) {
      //val contains the expected javascript object
      console.log(serverResponse);
});
```

How can I store the values correctly in json-server?

Comment: You should use `JSON.stringify(serverResponse)`  to save JSON object properly or either use this url (https://scotch.io/tutorials/json-server-as-a-fake-rest-api-in-frontend-development) to get some help to how to store data in JSON-Server

Comment: stringify the object post following data in db.json-
`{
      "{\"quizName\":\"Which Harry Potter Character Are You?\",\"characters\":[\"harry\",\"ron\",\"harmione\"],\"qa\":[{\"question\":\"do u play chess?\",\"answers\":[{\"name\":\"yes\",\"charscore\":[0,1,0]},{\"name\":\"no\",\"charscore\":[1,0,1]}]},{\"question\":\"do u have scar?\",\"answers\":[{\"name\":\"yes\",\"charscore\":[1,0,0]},{\"name\":\"no\",\"charscore\":[0,1,1]}]},{\"question\":\"du u spell magic?\",\"answers\":[{\"name\":\"yes\",\"charscore\":[0,0,1]},{\"name\":\"no\",\"charscore\":[1,1,0]}]}]}": "",
      "id": 1
    }`

Comment: stringifying is not helping here

Comment: Yes, it is the correct way to store any JSON object by using `stringify` and when you want to use it back as JSON object you can use `JSON.parse(serverResponse)`

Comment: Can you please tell, what exact issue you are facing while saving into json-server?

Comment: The file watched by json-server is db.json which should have expected json as defined in the question. Copying the same object into a temp var and jQuery posting the temp var again to json-server writes the unexpected object (defined in question). Tried using the JSON.stringify but still the output is not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the AJAX call to send stringify object and setting the `contentType: "application/json"` did the trick

Modified the AJAX call as below-

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.serverUrl,
      data: JSON.stringify(val),
      contentType: "application/json"
 });
```